# Consistent MATLAB plot size w/ different axis labels

Tags: graphing-functions, matlab

I'm trying to specify the sizes of two MATLAB figures in such a way that the graphs appear to be the same size, regardless of extra space used outside the axes.  Specifically, I'm want the white regions in the plots in the image below to be the same size.  Currently the entire figures are the same size, and I'm not sure how to fix that.

*Edit:* I'm using [this page](https://interfacegroup.ch/preparing-matlab-figures-for-publication/) as a resource.  I suspect the issue is with specifying the cm dimensions of the figure rather than allowing it to resize to fit the plot, but I don't know enough about the inner workings of the figures to say for sure.  Either size axis region is fine, I just want consistency.

[image]

These were generated with MATLAB R2016b using the code

```
fig1=figure(1);
ax1 = gca;
axis([0 2 0.625 1.375])
set(ax1,'XTick',1);
set(ax1,'YTick',1);
ax1.TickLabelInterpreter = 'latex';
set(ax1,'XTickLabel','$x$','Fontsize',15)
set(ax1,'YTickLabel',[])
xlabel('$x$','Interpreter','latex','Fontsize',15)
fig1.Units               = 'centimeters';
fig1.Position(3)         = 10;
fig1.Position(4)         = 9;
set(ax1,'LooseInset', max(get(ax1,'TightInset'), 0.02))

fig2=figure(2);
ax2 = gca;
axis([0 2 0.625 1.375])
set(ax2,'XTick',1);
set(ax2,'YTick',1);
ax2.TickLabelInterpreter = 'latex';
set(ax2,'XTickLabel','$x$','Fontsize',15)
set(ax2,'YTickLabel','$y$')
xlabel('$x$','Interpreter','latex','Fontsize',15)
ylabel('$y$','Interpreter','latex','Fontsize',15)
fig2.Units               = 'centimeters';
fig2.Position(3)         = 10;
fig2.Position(4)         = 9;
set(ax2,'LooseInset', max(get(ax2,'TightInset'), 0.02))
```

Comment: Is the y-axis label of the first plot always empty?

Comment: @DavidScholz Yes, one has a label and one doesn't.

Comment: Although it doesn't matter which one is first.

Comment: Is the tick label required? You are currently setting two labels, the $y$ tick label and the normal y label. The same for the x axis.

Comment: @DavidScholz Yes, I need both.  In practice they are not the same label, and there may be more than one tick label, this was just an easily reproducible example of the issue.  If I can find a solution that works on the example I'm confident I can make it work in general.

Comment: I have tried the following: setting the size of each figure after layouting, setting the size of figure 1 to the sizes of figure 2, setting the OuterPosition of figures 1 to the OuterPosition of figure 2 (since the ticklabel is empty in figure 1), setting an empty placeholder, set the same labels but for figure 1 set the visibility flag to false. Nothing worked so I tried the following hack: set the same labels for both figures and set the colors to white for figure 1. Problem: the \color markup only works in tex not for latex for some reason and the size still changes. I'm out of time, sorry.

Comment: You could still use subplots, this should work.

Comment: @DavidScholz no worries, I appreciate your efforts.  I'm avoiding using subplots because I need to import these into LaTeX and I want to be able to caption/reference them separately.